# Filtrar una lista de diccionarios y agruparlos por los valores repetidos

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo la siguiente lista de diccionarios en Python:

```
lista = [
    { 'procedimiento_id':1, 'datos': [ 
        { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 },     
        { 'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
    ]}, 
    { 'procedimiento_id':2, 'datos': [ 
        { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 },    
        { 'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
    ]}, 
    { 'procedimiento_id':3, 'datos': [ 
        { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
    ]}
]
```

Aquí notamos que procedimiento_id: 1 tiene los mismos datos que procedimiento_id 2 en su clave 'datos', entonces ese sería un grupo , pero procedimiento_id: 3 solo tiene un diccionario , por lo tanto es diferente y sería otro grupo

mi proposito es crear grupos de esos mismos dicionarios , agrupados si los procedimiento_id tienen los mismos datos que otros, misma especialidad_id y mismo valor de tiempo_minutos

resultado  esperado:

```
grupo1 = [
    { 'procedimiento_id':1, 'datos': [ 
        { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 },   
        {'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
    ]}, 
    { 'procedimiento_id':2, 'datos': [ 
        { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 }, 
        { 'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
    ]} 
]

grupo2 = { 'procedimiento_id':3, 'datos': [ 
    { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
]}
```

Comment: Recuerda editar tu pregunta para actualizarla con la nueva información que has encontrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un modulo llamado [Itertool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) el cual posee muchas funciones de gran utilidad, dentro de dichas funciones esta una que te puede ayudar mucho a agrupar que es [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Dicha funcion como su nombre lo indica agrupa los elementos de un iterable en base a una clave (que para tus fines es `datos`) y retorna un iterable(lista) que contiene dichos grupos:

```
from itertools import groupby

lista = [{'procedimiento_id':1, 'datos': [ {'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 }, {'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } ] }, {'procedimiento_id':2, 'datos': [ {'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 }, {'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } ] }, {'procedimiento_id':3, 'datos': [ {'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } ] } ] 

groups = []

for index, items in enumerate(groupby(lista, lambda x: x['datos'])):
    key, group_items = items
    groups.append({'group_{}'.format(index+1): list(group_items)})

# o utilizando list comprehension
# groups = [
#     {"group_{}".format(index + 1): list(items[1])}
#     for index, items in enumerate(groupby(lista, lambda x: x["datos"]))
# ]
```

Y este es el resultado:

```
[
    {
        "group_1": [
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 1,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                    {"especialidad_id": 4, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 2,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                    {"especialidad_id": 4, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "group_2": [
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 3,
                "datos": [{"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0}],
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Difiere un poco en lo que planteas ya que en lugar de definir una variable para cada grupo tienes un listado con tus grupos al que puedes acceder mediante su indice.

---

#### Update #1

Después hacer la prueba con un [listado mas grande](https://pym.dev/p/3at4u/) se comprobó que se estaban mostrando mas grupos (5) de los esperados(3).
Tomando en referencia el enunciado que colocaste en el enlace externo

> se deberían crear 3 grupos , la lista de todos los que tienen el tiempo_minutos "17.5700934579439"  y "254.766355140187" , la lista de
> los que tienen el tiempo_minutos 10.0 y la lista de los que tienen el
> tiempo_minutos 5.0

En el mismo detallas que deseas agrupar por `tiempo_minutos`

He aquí el código actualizado en donde ordeno el listado en base a tiempo_minutos y especialidad_id y agrupo mediante esas mismas claves:

```
# Esta función reemplaza la función anónima empleada en el código anterior para evitar repetir el mismo código y se la pasamos como clave de ordenación y de agrupación 
def key_func(x):
    return x['datos'][0]['especialidad_id'], x['datos'][0]['tiempo_minutos']
    
groups = []

lista = sorted(lista, key=key_func)

for index, items in enumerate(groupby(lista, key=key_func)):
    key, group_items = items
    groups.append({'group_{}'.format(index+1): list(group_items)})
```

Resultado:

```
[
    {
        "group_1": [
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 144,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 5.0},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 5.0},
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group_2": [
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 139,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 143,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 10.0},
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "group_3": [
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 132,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 133,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 134,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 135,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 136,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 137,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 138,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 140,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 141,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
            {
                "procedimiento_id": 142,
                "datos": [
                    {"especialidad_id": 3, "tiempo_minutos": 17.5700934579439},
                    {"especialidad_id": 29, "tiempo_minutos": 254.766355140187},
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Saludos.

Comment: Cordial saludo amigo , muchas gracias , aunque he realizado la prueba con una lista más grande , y me crea más grupos de los que debería.

Comment: Puedes compartir esa lista mediante este enlace https://www.pythonmorsels.com/paste/ para evaluarla.

Comment: Listo amigo ya te dejé la lista y te describí el motivo del porque no crea los 3 grupos: este es el link: https://pym.dev/p/3at4u/

Comment: Recuerda actualizar tu respuesta con la nueva información.

Answer (score 0):

La solución para que ordenara correctamente por grupos, fue convertir el key "datos" a string

```
lista = [
{ 'procedimiento_id':1, 'datos': str([ 
    { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 },     
    { 'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
])}, 
{ 'procedimiento_id':2, 'datos': str([ 
    { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 },    
    { 'especialidad_id': 4 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
])}, 
{ 'procedimiento_id':3, 'datos': str([ 
    { 'especialidad_id': 3 , 'tiempo_minutos': 10.0 } 
])}]
```

el código funciona así

Comment: Amigo, en tu pregunta colocas AGRUPAR por valores repetidos no ORDENAR y en tu respuesta básicamente no estas mostrando el proceso de agrupación al que haces referencia en tu pregunta.